# How to pass a second condition to or_Where_in in laravel 3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-3

Thanks for checking.

Please i am building a query using laravel where i am selecting posts/question under a topic a user is following. then select also posts/questions from users that the current user is following. i used this code to run the query

```
$posts=DB::table('posts')
                ->where('posts.type','=',Session::get('sortby'))
                ->where_in('posts.topicid',$ary)
                ->or_where_in('posts.uid',$uu)
                ->join('users','posts.uid','=','users.id')
                ->join('topics', 'posts.topicid', '=', 'topics.id')
                ->order_by('posts.id','desc')
                ->take(Session::get('totalm'))
                ->get(array('posts.id','posts.uid','posts.title',
                'users.username','users.keyname','posts.topicid',
                'posts.posted_at','topics.name','topics.image','users.dp',
                'posts.type','users.info','posts.post'));
```

`Session::get('sortby')` return the users selected sorting which can be any of these 1,2,0 
the query return results but the problem is that it return all posts and questions from the users he is following ignoring the sorting which is ment to return either post or questions. `->or_where_in('posts.uid',$uu)` the `$uu` is an array of theses users.
Please is there a way i can pass second condition to the `or_where_in` to return only the posts from theses users who post type is either 1,2 or 0 as returned by the session variable `Session::get('sortby')`.

Please i will appreciate any help or idea that will help me achieve this. this is the 3rd day i am tying to fix this.

Comment: Take a look at [`advanced wheres`](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres) from the Laravel docs.

Comment: I finally got an answer to my own question after trying other solutions while waiting for someone to help.
the solution is to use `->having()` to run the final filter to make sure all returned result are of the same type.

I just added this line

    `->having('type', '=', Session::get('sortby'))// this line did ``the margic`

`type` is either `1,2,0`
i hope this helps someone.

Comment: Sejan Parikh thanks for your reply. i am using laravel 3. it is faster without many vendor packages i wont use.